# Splitting ip and port in ip:port format using batch

Tags: batch-file, proxy, ip

For the program I am currently working on I am taking a value, which is a proxy in ip:port format, I need to be able to split the ip and port to different variables so that a different program that needs ip and port separate will be able to work. The program is basically an automated ip/proxy switcher for minecraft, just for in game reasons, I have all the code working except for the part that actually changed the proxy. I am not getting any error message, only that I don't actually know what code to write. Anyways, here is my code.

```
@echo off
color b
title minecraft proxy switcher
set nLine=0
echo input full path to text file containing proxies
set /P "filepath=>"
echo end >> %filepath%
:top
cls
set /A nLine=%nLine%+1
echo now at proxy number %nLine%
CALL :ReadNthLine "%filepath%" %nLine%
PAUSE >NUL & goto:top
GOTO :EOF
::***************************************************************************************
:ReadNthLine File nLine
FOR /F %%A IN ('^<"%~1" FIND /C /V ""') DO IF %2 GTR %%A (ECHO Error: No such line %2. 1>&2 & EXIT /b 1)
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A IN ('^<"%~1" FIND /N /V "" ^| FINDSTR /B /C:"[%2]"') DO set http_proxy=%%B
goto finish
::***************************************************************************************
:finish
if %http_proxy%==end (
                cls
                echo all proxies have been used
                echo will return to top of list in 5 seconds
                TIMEOUT /T 5 /NOBREAK
                set nLine=0
                goto top
            )   
java -DsocksProxyHost=ip -DsocksProxyPort=port -Xmx800m -jar MinecraftLauncher.exe
echo New ip is %http_proxy%
echo waiting for user input
echo press any key for a new ip
pause
goto top
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, also if you notice something else that's badly written or incorrect in my code please tell me.

Comment: Would help to see what the input file looks like so we know what to parse out of the file.

Comment: The input file is a list of proxy servers with the ip:port format, for example:                                             127.0.0.1:80                                                                    192.168.1.1:8080 and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

split the string with a `for`, using proper tokens and delimiters:

```
set "line=192.168.1.1:8080"
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ("%line%") do (
  set server=%%a
  set port=%%b
)
echo Server %server% Port %port%
```

here is a basic code skeleton which processes the file line after line (your way works, but this is way easier):

```
@echo off
set /p "filepath=File: "

:top
set n=0
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in (%filepath%) do call :process %%a %%b
timeout 5
goto :top

:process
echo trying %n%
set /a n+=1
echo   host: %1
echo   port: %2
pause
goto :eof
```